# PHP - Tinting an image with GD library coming from a user's form data with $ _POST

Tags: php, post, gd

I have an image that looks like this:

[image]

Which comprises of basehair.png merged with base.php in order to create one single image of a model with hair. The goal is to change the colour of the hair on the model to fit the user's choice of hair colour. For this, I have a file with the html form:

INDEX.PHP

```
<p>Choose your hair color:</p><form method="post" action="generate_illu.php">
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="blonde">Blonde
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="brown">Brown
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="black">Black
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="red">Red
<input style="border-style: solid;"type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="submitBtn"></form>
```

And a php file with the following code
(GENERATE_ILLU.PHP)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitBtn']))
{
   $haircolor = $_POST['radio'];
   header ("Content-type: image/png");


if ($haircolor == "blonde")
{
    $source = imagecreatefrompng("images/hairbase.png"); // The base hair is the source
    $destination = imagecreatefrompng("images/base.png"); // The base model is the destination
    imagealphablending($source, true);
    imagesavealpha($source, true);
    imagefilter($source, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0, 150, 100, 100); //php function used to apply a tint to "change" the colour of the hair. Works fine on its own
    $width_source = imagesx($source);
    $height_source = imagesy($source);
    $width_destination = imagesx($destination);
    $height_destination = imagesy($destination);

    imagecopy($destination, $source, 53, 0, 0, 0, $width_source, $height_source);
    imagepng($destination);

}

elseif ($haircolor == "brown")
{
    $source = imagecreatefrompng("images/hairbase.png"); 
    $destination = imagecreatefrompng("images/base.png"); 
    imagealphablending($source, true);
    imagesavealpha($source, true);
    imagefilter($source, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0, 0, 200, 200);
    $width_source = imagesx($source);
    $height_source = imagesy($source);
    $width_destination = imagesx($destination);
    $height_destination = imagesy($destination);

    imagecopy($destination, $source, 53, 0, 0, 0, $width_source, $height_source);
    imagepng($destination);

}

elseif ($haircolor == "black")
{
    $source = imagecreatefrompng("images/hairbase.png"); // The base hair is the source
    $destination = imagecreatefrompng("images/base.png"); // La photo est la destination
    imagealphablending($source, true);
    imagesavealpha($source, true);
    imagefilter($source, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0, 150, 100, 100);
    $width_source = imagesx($source);
    $height_source = imagesy($source);
    $width_destination = imagesx($destination);
    $height_destination = imagesy($destination);

    imagecopy($destination, $source, 53, 0, 0, 0, $width_source, $height_source);
    imagepng($destination);
}

elseif ($haircolor == "red")
{
    $source = imagecreatefrompng("images/hairbase.png"); // The base hair is the source
    $destination = imagecreatefrompng("images/base.png"); // La photo est la destination
    imagealphablending($source, true);
    imagesavealpha($source, true);
    imagefilter($source, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0, 250, 200, 100);
    $width_source = imagesx($source);
    $height_source = imagesy($source);
    $width_destination = imagesx($destination);
    $height_destination = imagesy($destination);

    imagecopy($destination, $source, 53, 0, 0, 0, $width_source, $height_source);
    imagepng($destination);
}
else
{
    echo "Please choose one of the proposed hair colors.";
}}?>
```

While the "else" section of this condition works fine, the other parts simply wont change colours. I suspect maybe this has something to do with imagefilter($source, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0, 150, 100, 100); , but when I used it alone, outside the if/else statement, it worked fine.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can't see anything obvious. Your code is repeated almost in entirety in each `elseif` section. I'd just make an array of hair colours to RGBA values, eg `$hairColours = ['blonde' => [0, 150, 100, 100], 'brown' => [0, 0, 200, 200], ...]` and apply those in the code, eg `list($r, $g, $b, $a) = $hairColours[$haircolor]; imagefilter($source, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $r, $g, $b, $a);`